# Не работает сервер на Django

Tags: python, ubuntu, django

Установил питон и джанго успешно - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uXSt.jpg

После он предлагает перейти на http://127.0.0.1:8000/ .Захожу, но подключения нет. Использую ubuntu os. В чем проблема?

Comment: А вы, простите, зайти-то пытаетесь ПЕРЕД нажатием Ctrl+C?

Answer (score -1):

Запускать нужно от рута. Ввел sudo -s -H, а после python manage.py runserver

Comment: Вот не надо никогда джангу от рута запускать

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?